# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2) Python Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, knn, image-classification

i'm newbie for using python in google colab, i have to finish my project classes now (classification image using KNN algorithm). please help me to fix this code. Thank you

```
# Importing the dataset
dataset = ('/content/dataset/Validation/')
X = dataset
y = dataset

# Cleaning up variables to prevent loading data multiple times (which may cause memory issue)
try:
   del X_train, y_train
   del X_test, y_test
   print('Clear previously loaded data.')
except:
   pass

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset)

# As a sanity check, we print out the size of the training and test data.
print('Training data shape: ', X_train.shape)
print('Training labels shape: ', y_train.shape)
print('Test data shape: ', X_test.shape)
print('Test labels shape: ', y_test.shape)
```

i have to finish my project classes now (classification image using KNN algorithm)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.  That said, are you certain that ```train-test_split(dataset)``` returns 4 values?

Comment: Read the `train_test_split` [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) carefully.

Comment: yes, but both `X` and `y` are just pointing to `dataset`. Instead, X should get the data and y should take the labels. Sometimes the last column is the y but we cannot assume that without having the column names and descriptions, which haven't been provided.

Comment: If you just want `dataset` to be split into test and train sets then simply use `X_train, X_test = train_test_split(dataset)` . You might want to look at the other options in the docs to change the size of the splits etc.

Answer (score 0):

train_test_split returns 2 sets for each dataset you pass to it. And you pass only 1 dataset to the function. If you want to get 4 sub-datasets, you need to pass 2 datasets to the function.

So, replace your line by:

```
X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

Note: X and y are the same in your code, it shouldn't be the case. X should contain all columns except the target values, y should contain a single column with these target values.

Moreover, you should take care of additional parameters, such as `random_state` to ensure reproducibility of your code, for instance. As said in other comments, read the doc!